# Filter and send emails

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having difficulties to develop an automatic email sending spreadsheet, in this case I need it to filter by supplier and by delay time to then send the email to the specific supplier to control deliveries. How can I create a code and that can "broke/filter" the table by vendor and by time and create a new workbook to send attached in email for this vendor, I've tried (image bellow) but the code isn't works. Do you have any other Idea this can be done? [In this worksheet I need to filter the supplier in the column AC ad the column AE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGGU0.png)

On the spreadsheets that are created in this process, I need that only the main spreadsheet remains available, the others must be deleted

```
Sub enviarEmails()

    Dim regiaoDosDados As Range
    Dim outlookAplicacao As Object
    Dim outlookEmail As Object
    
    Set outlookAplicacao = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outlookEmail = outlookAplicacao.CreateItem(0)
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    Range("C1:L13").Select
    
    Set regiaoDosDados = Nothing
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set regiaoDosDados = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    With outlookEmail
        .To = ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Value
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Boletim escolar " & ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Value
        .HTMLBody = "<font face=Calibri> Ola, " & ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Value & _
        "<br><br>Segue suas notas qualquer duvida favor entrar em contato." & _
        "<br><br>" & TabelaParaHTML(regiaoDosDados) & _
        "<br><br><b><span style='color:red'>ATENCAO!!!</span></b>" & _
        "<br><br><a href='https://www.google.com/'>Clique aqui para acessar a central do aluno.</a> " & _
        "<br><br>Atenciosamente" & _
        "<br><br><img border='0' src='C:\Assinatura\Udemy Assinatura.jpg'>"
        .Save 'Save = Salvar, Display = Criar e abrir, Send = Enviar
    End With
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    Set outlookEmail = Nothing
    Set outlookAplicacao = Nothing

End Sub


Function TabelaParaHTML(regiaoDosDados As Range)

    Dim FluxoDeTexto As Object
    Dim temporarioWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim objetoDoSistemaDeArquivos As Object
    Dim arquivoTemporario As String
    
    
    arquivoTemporario = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
    
    
    'Copia o intervalo e cria uma nova pasta de trabalho para colar os dados
    regiaoDosDados.Copy
    Set temporarioWorkBook = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With temporarioWorkBook.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False 'Colar os valores copiados
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False 'Colar o formato cores e entre outros
        .Cells(1).Select
    End With
    
    'Publica a planilha em um arquivo htm
    With temporarioWorkBook.PublishObjects.Add( _
            SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
            Filename:=arquivoTemporario, _
            Sheet:=temporarioWorkBook.Sheets(1).Name, _
            Source:=temporarioWorkBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
            HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
            .Publish (True)
    End With
    
    'Lê todos os dados do arquivo .htm no TabelaParaHTML
    Set objetoDoSistemaDeArquivos = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set FluxoDeTexto = objetoDoSistemaDeArquivos.GetFile(arquivoTemporario).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    TabelaParaHTML = FluxoDeTexto.readall
    FluxoDeTexto.Close
    TabelaParaHTML = Replace(TabelaParaHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                            "align=left x:publishsource=")
                            
    'Fecha o arquivo temporário
    temporarioWorkBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                            
    'Eclui o arquivo temporário que foi criado e usado
    Kill arquivoTemporario
    
    
    Set FluxoDeTexto = Nothing
    Set temporarioWorkBook = Nothing
    Set objetoDoSistemaDeArquivos = Nothing
    

End Function
```

Comment: your image does not show any filter buttons. The image only show 3 rows and some headers, no Vendor and Time columns! What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Hello, I have created a new question to explain this, can you help me there?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69146076/filter-and-send-email-in-excel @ElioFernandes